# CSS overlapping in React

Tags: reactjs

I have 2 different pages and a `.css` file for each page. Both have a `class` selector with the same name, but only one of them is applied. I've only worked with react-native so far, and had both the content and the styling in the same file. I couldn't figure out what is happening...

Let's say we have the following css class:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Even if the css file is not imported in one file, the class is applied to a `div`, if it's given in `className`.

For example, we have 2 files: `CarPage.tsx` and `BikePage.tsx`. The `container` class is imported in `CarPage`, but it's used in `BikePage` and it is applied. Does anyone know if this is how it should work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In React, once CSS is imported, it will be "combined" and applied to the entire DOM. React uses CSS files as global scope. 
In order to achieve locally scoped CSS, you will have to use:

#### [CSS module](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/)

Create `[name].module.css` file then:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styles from './example.module.css';

class Example extends Component {
    render() {
        return <button className={styles.container }>Button</button>;
    }
 }
 export default Example;
```

#### [using libraries such as styled-components).](https://styled-components.com/)

```
  class Example extends Component {
         const Button = styled.button`
           background: transparent;
           border-radius: 3px;
           color: red;
           margin: 0 1em;
           padding: 0.25em 1em;
           `
          render(){
           return  <Button /> 
           };

 }
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me! Tried it with CSS module.